# My storm topology fails after running for 10 days

Tags: apache, apache-storm

My storm topology fails after running for 10 days , when I deploy the same topology (same JAR) with new name it runs well till date, so my question is that what are the new resources got allocated for newly deployed Storm topology including zookeeper memory. If I redeployed that topology with OLD name its fails again in few hours.

I have not done any changes before deploying it with new topology name.

Is that Storm topology consume any memory space on worker node after running for longer period which i need to take care of?

Comment: Please describe what you mean when you say that your topology "fails". Do you get error logs, does it crash with OOME or what do you mean? Also you should consider listing the components used by your topology (spouts, bolts, is it Trident?) as well as the Storm version.

Comment: what I mean by fail is that after analyzing Storm logs I can see one port stops processing the tuples, that results in huge failures at Spout.It just print the logmetrics info for hours.No sign of tuple processing in the logs

Comment: 2018-11-10 04:17:26.540 o.a.s.m.LoggingMetricsConsumer [INFO] 1541823446 wn0-stormp.t3rhv0qy3pnuzkwi2ieuucmbpf.ax.internal.cloudapp.net:6700  -1:__system    memory/heap.initBytes   [230686720]
2018-11-10 04:17:26.540 o.a.s.m.LoggingMetricsConsumer [INFO] 1541823446 wn0-stormp.t3rhv0qy3pnuzkwi2ieuucmbpf.ax.internal.cloudapp.net:6700  -1:__system    __receive.sojourn_time_ [9952.0]
2018-11-10 04:17:26.540 o.a.s.m.LoggingMetricsConsumer [INFO] 1541823446 wn0-stormp.t3rhv0qy3pnuzkwi2ieuucmbpf.ax.internal.cloudapp.net:6700  -1:__system    __receive.overflow

Comment: Its not trident topology , it contain one spout and eight bolts

Answer (score 0):

I'm familiar with at least one bug in Storm pre-1.0.0 that can cause workers to hang. If you aren't on the latest Storm version, try upgrading.

Other than that, your best bet for debugging this is to use `jstack` or `kill -3` on the worker JVM to figure out what your hanging worker is doing. You may also want to enable debug logging if it doesn't harm your performance too much. You do this by doing `config.setDebug(true);` when setting up the topology.

Once you know why the worker isn't processing tuples you can try posting the stack trace here, maybe there's an issue in Storm.